# (Macbook M1 Pro) flutter run problem with cocoapods

Tags: ios, flutter, macos, dart, mobile

After installing the camera dependancy and running flutter run on my new Macbook M1, i got problems with cocoapods, which I successfully installed.
After trying the recommended command "gem pristine ffi --version 1.15.5", i received no error:
output:
Restoring gems to pristine condition...
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
Restored ffi-1.15.5

But when running flutter run I got the same error

flutter run output:
`

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 14 Pro Max in debug mode...
Running pod install...                                             668ms
CocoaPods' output:
↳
      Preparing

    Analyzing dependencies

    Inspecting targets to integrate
      Using `ARCHS` setting to build architectures of target `Pods-Runner`: (``)

    Fetching external sources
    -> Fetching podspec for `Flutter` from `Flutter`
    -> Fetching podspec for `camera_avfoundation` from
    `.symlinks/plugins/camera_avfoundation/ios`

    Resolving dependencies of `Podfile`
      CDN: trunk Relative path: CocoaPods-version.yml exists! Returning local
      because checking is only performed in repo update

    Comparing resolved specification to the sandbox manifest
      A Flutter
      A camera_avfoundation

    Downloading dependencies

    -> Installing Flutter (1.0.0)

    -> Installing camera_avfoundation (0.0.1)
      - Running pre install hooks
      - Running pre integrate hooks

    Generating Pods project
      - Creating Pods project
      - Installing files into Pods project
        - Adding source files
        - Adding frameworks
        - Adding libraries
        - Adding resources
        - Adding development pod helper files
        - Linking headers
      - Installing Pod Targets
        - Installing target `Flutter` iOS 9.0
        - Installing target `camera_avfoundation` iOS 9.0
          - Copying module map file to `Pods/Target Support
          Files/camera_avfoundation/camera_avfoundation.modulemap`
          - Generating Info.plist file at `Pods/Target Support
          Files/camera_avfoundation/camera_avfoundation-Info.plist`
          - Generating dummy source at `Pods/Target Support
          Files/camera_avfoundation/camera_avfoundation-dummy.m`
      - Installing Aggregate Targets
        - Installing target `Pods-Runner` iOS 11.0
          - Generating Info.plist file at `Pods/Target Support
          Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner-Info.plist`
          - Generating module map file at `Pods/Target Support
          Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.modulemap`
          - Generating umbrella header at `Pods/Target Support
          Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner-umbrella.h`
          - Generating dummy source at `Pods/Target Support
          Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner-dummy.m`
      - Generating deterministic UUIDs
      - Stabilizing target UUIDs
      - Running post install hooks
    [!] An error occurred while processing the post-install hook of the Podfile.

    undefined local variable or method `continue' for
    #<Pod::Podfile:0x000000010725cbc0
    @defined_in_file=#<Pathname:/Users/laurent/development/personal/flutter/jemp
    i/ios/Podfile>, @internal_hash={},
    @root_target_definitions=[#<Pod::Podfile::TargetDefinition label=Pods>],
    @current_target_definition=#<Pod::Podfile::TargetDefinition label=Pods>,
    @post_install_callback=#<Proc:0x000000010727dde8
    /Users/laurent/development/personal/flutter/jempi/ios/Podfile:37>,
    @installation_options=#<Pod::Installer::InstallationOptions:0x000000010732c9
    10 @clean=true, @deduplicate_targets=true, @deterministic_uuids=true,
    @integrate_targets=true, @lock_pod_sources=true,
    @warn_for_multiple_pod_sources=true,
    @warn_for_unused_master_specs_repo=true,
    @share_schemes_for_development_pods=false,
    @disable_input_output_paths=false, @preserve_pod_file_structure=false,
    @generate_multiple_pod_projects=false, @incremental_installation=false,
    @skip_pods_project_generation=false>>

          continue if xcframework_file.start_with?(".") # Hidden file, possibly
          on external disk.
          ^^^^^^^^

    /Users/laurent/development/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/bin/podhelper.rb:6
    3:in `block (2 levels) in flutter_additional_ios_build_settings'
    /Users/laurent/development/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/bin/podhelper.rb:6
    2:in `each_child'
    /Users/laurent/development/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/bin/podhelper.rb:6
    2:in `block in flutter_additional_ios_build_settings'
    /Users/laurent/development/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/bin/podhelper.rb:5
    1:in `each'
    /Users/laurent/development/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/bin/podhelper.rb:5
    1:in `flutter_additional_ios_build_settings'
    /Users/laurent/development/personal/flutter/jempi/ios/Podfile:39:in `block
    (3 levels) in from_ruby'
    /Users/laurent/development/personal/flutter/jempi/ios/Podfile:38:in `each'
    /Users/laurent/development/personal/flutter/jempi/ios/Podfile:38:in `block
    (2 levels) in from_ruby'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.3/lib
    /cocoapods-core/podfile.rb:196:in `post_install!'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/coco
    apods/installer.rb:945:in `run_podfile_post_install_hook'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/coco
    apods/installer.rb:933:in `block in run_podfile_post_install_hooks'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/coco
    apods/user_interface.rb:149:in `message'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/coco
    apods/installer.rb:932:in `run_podfile_post_install_hooks'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/coco
    apods/installer.rb:331:in `block (2 levels) in create_and_save_projects'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/coco
    apods/installer/xcode/pods_project_generator/pods_project_writer.rb:61:in
    `write!'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/coco
    apods/installer.rb:330:in `block in create_and_save_projects'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/coco
    apods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/coco
    apods/installer.rb:309:in `create_and_save_projects'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/coco
    apods/installer.rb:301:in `generate_pods_project'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/coco
    apods/installer.rb:180:in `integrate'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/coco
    apods/installer.rb:167:in `install!'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/coco
    apods/command/install.rb:52:in `run'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/c
    ommand.rb:334:in `run'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/coco
    apods/command.rb:52:in `run'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/bin/pod:
    55:in `<top (required)>'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/bin/pod:25:in `load'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/bin/pod:25:in `<main>'

    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/coco
    apods/installer.rb:947:in `rescue in run_podfile_post_install_hook'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/coco
    apods/installer.rb:944:in `run_podfile_post_install_hook'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/coco
    apods/installer.rb:933:in `block in run_podfile_post_install_hooks'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/coco
    apods/user_interface.rb:149:in `message'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/coco
    apods/installer.rb:932:in `run_podfile_post_install_hooks'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/coco
    apods/installer.rb:331:in `block (2 levels) in create_and_save_projects'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/coco
    apods/installer/xcode/pods_project_generator/pods_project_writer.rb:61:in
    `write!'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/coco
    apods/installer.rb:330:in `block in create_and_save_projects'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/coco
    apods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/coco
    apods/installer.rb:309:in `create_and_save_projects'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/coco
    apods/installer.rb:301:in `generate_pods_project'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/coco
    apods/installer.rb:180:in `integrate'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/coco
    apods/installer.rb:167:in `install!'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/coco
    apods/command/install.rb:52:in `run'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/c
    ommand.rb:334:in `run'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/coco
    apods/command.rb:52:in `run'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/bin/pod:
    55:in `<top (required)>'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/bin/pod:25:in `load'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.11.3/libexec/bin/pod:25:in `<main>'

Error output from CocoaPods:
↳
    Ignoring ffi-1.15.5 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine
    ffi --version 1.15.5

Error running pod install
Error launching application on iPhone 14 Pro Max.
```

`

Here my Podfile

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '11.0'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
  end
end
```

Here my pubspec

```
name: jempi
description: A new Flutter project.

# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `flutter pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: "none" # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.17.6 <3.0.0"

# Dependencies specify other packages that your package needs in order to work.
# To automatically upgrade your package dependencies to the latest versions
# consider running `flutter pub upgrade --major-versions`. Alternatively,
# dependencies can be manually updated by changing the version numbers below to
# the latest version available on pub.dev. To see which dependencies have newer
# versions available, run `flutter pub outdated`.
dependencies:
  camera: ^0.10.0+4
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec
# The following section is specific to Flutter packages.
flutter:
  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - assets/img/
  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware
  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages
  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

I tried reinstalling cocoapods and ffi several times, also using sudo gem install cocoapods
sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi

Answer (score 0):

basic steps for solving pod issues in flutter are:-

- pod deintegrate
- pod clean
- pod upgrade
- pod install
  and solve the specific pod errors if you find any
  advice to go with Xcode while solving pod issues

Comment: On pod install i got:


[!] CocoaPods did not set the base configuration of your project because your project already has a custom config set. In order for CocoaPods integration to work at all, please either set the base configurations of the target `Runner` to `Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.release.xcconfig` or include the `Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.release.xcconfig` in your build configuration (`Flutter/Debug.xcconfig`).

Comment: Fixed pod errors.
Now i got build errors:

Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **

Parse Issue (Xcode): Module 'camera_avfoundation' not found
/Users/laurent/development/personal/flutter/jempi/ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m:11:8


Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 14 Pro Max.

Comment: may be you have used such a library which is available only on android or use it to the available version on pub.dev